# Is it a problem to eat animal leftovers

Tags: halacha, minhag, animals, eating

Is it true that there is a Jewish custom not to eat after animals (even if not mius issue (ie the person eating does not know))

ie if a rat ate a piece of a fruit I can't just cut off that part and eat the rest

If yes, what is the source?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Talmud Tractate Horayos 13b - "Eating something that a mouse (rat) or cat nibbled on, causes one to forget their learning"

So, the whole piece is discarded.